# Is MongoDB Enterprise required to run MongoDB Charts?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-charts

According to this link [Mongodb charts is now generally available](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/mongodb-charts-is-now-generally-available) it requires a `MongoDB Enterprise Server on-premises,` in order to run.

However when I visit: https://docs.mongodb.com/charts/19.12/installation/ it says that only a `MongoDB Charts requires a MongoDB database to store Charts users, dashboards, data sources, etc`

So I'm confused on which it is? Can I run it locally for free or do I require a enterprise license?

Comment: This may be better asked to Mongo support. Even if we could give an answer here, chances are it'll be outdated sometime soon, which then is worse than no answer.

Comment: Already have but they're pretty slow unfortunately.

Comment: quay.io/mongodb/charts:19.12.1 definitely works with standalone CE from technical perspective. Basically I run it for free. If you are concerned about licenses/pricing for legal purposes - as David said SO is not the best place to ask.

Comment: I've updated my question as I wasn't really interested in the license side, I was more interested in if it was technically possible to run.

Answer (score 1):

I've updated my question for future lookers.

No a MongoDB enterprise license is not currently required to ***run*** MongoDB Charts.

However you will require a license to run it officially, however there is currently a free trial for it. You can find more information in my cross post to their forum.

https://community.mongodb.com/t/how-does-pricing-work-for-mongodb-charts-on-prem/1245